# Flow errors on <React.Fragment> or <></>, but not <Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, react-fragment

I am using `react` **v16.3.0** and `flow-bin` **v0.69.0**

Using react [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) with either `<React.Fragment>` or the shorthand `<></>` syntax like so

```
import React from 'react'

const ComponentA = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div>Component</div>
    <div>A</div>
  </React.Fragment>
)

const ComponentB = () => (
  <>
    <div>Component</div>
    <div>B</div>
  </>
)
```

Flow complains with the following error (it's an indentical error for both, just showing output for `ComponentA` here)

```
Cannot get React.Fragment because property Fragment is missing in object type [1].

  24│ const ComponentA = () => (
  25│   <React.Fragment>
  26│     <div>Component</div>
  27│     <div>A</div>
  28│   </React.Fragment>

 /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_2349df3a/react.js
 251│   declare export default {|
 252│     +DOM: typeof DOM,
 253│     +PropTypes: typeof PropTypes,
 254│     +version: typeof version,
 255│     +initializeTouchEvents: typeof initializeTouchEvents,
 256│     +checkPropTypes: typeof checkPropTypes,
 257│     +createClass: typeof createClass,
 258│     +createElement: typeof createElement,
 259│     +cloneElement: typeof cloneElement,
 260│     +createFactory: typeof createFactory,
 261│     +isValidElement: typeof isValidElement,
 262│     +Component: typeof Component,
 263│     +PureComponent: typeof PureComponent,
 264│     +Children: typeof Children,
 265│   |};
```

With an explicit import of `Fragment`, however, flow does not complain.

```
import { Fragment, default as React } from 'react'

const ComponentC = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <div>Component</div>
    <div>C</div>
  </Fragment>
)
```

What is going on here? I would like to use the `<></>` Fragment shorthand syntax, and this issue is stopping me from doing that for now.

When I dig into the `react.js` lib def referenced in the error it does appear that the error is factually correct - the export of `Fragment` *is* defined and Fragment *is not* defined as a property on the default export.

But the flow docs [state that flow has support for react Fragments](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#flow)  from **v0.59** onwards.

So is this actually a gap in support that still exists? Or am I doing something wrong? Perhaps I somehow have an outdated lib def or have things configured wrong? I can't find anything googling for the error message, which leads me to suspect it's an issue with my setup. Also I can't quite believe that this wouldn't work out the box.

Comment: This may be fixed in 16.3

Comment: Issue is still present in React **16.3**. Have updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fix to include `React.Fragment` in the definition is included in this commit:
https://github.com/facebook/flow/commit/b76ad725177284681d483247e89739c292ed982b

It should be available in flow `0.71`

Comment: Thanks for the update, good to know. When this lands I'll accept your answer :-)

Comment: flow 0.71 is out. I tried your snippet and it's not complaining anymore. The change about Fragment is mentioned in the changelog : https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.71.0

Comment: Can also confirm it's working now with 0.71.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `import * as React from 'react'` to fix this :)

Comment: Thanks for that - it does make the flow error go away. However it also takes `React` out of scope meaning JSX doesn't compile. I know I could throw some workaround into the build for that, but it's quite non-standard and doesn't feel worth it just to remove this annoyance (I'd rather just have the extra verbosity of importing and using `<Fragment>`). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Actually, this is the syntax I use in my whole app. Arguably, `import * as React from 'react'` is the more correct syntax, and the other is just a Babel shim and not real ES6. https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/es6-import-as-react-vs-import-react/360/10

Answer (score 2):

As simple as:

```
import * as React from 'react'

const Component = (): React.Element<typeof React.Fragment> => (
  <>
    <span> / </span>
    <span> \ </span>
  </>
)

export default Component
```

Comment: So, not that simple then, really, unless you have this magic recipe handy. :)

Comment: Simple enough if you understand how Flow (and similar type systems) works.